# Remove/change specific object from an ArrayList

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, methods

I'm building a simplified inventory program for a "hardware store" in Java. I want to register the items by name and quantity into an array, and also remove or change the quantity if the item gets sold.

i believe i'm done with 80 percent of the work. I just can't figure out how to remove or change the object after storing it. Has this something to do with the `equals(Object obj)` method? I'm finding it hard to understand how to use the method in my case.

Class for the hardware items:

```
public class Items {

    private String item;
    private String quantity;

    public Items(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return item;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return item;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item=item;
    }


    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity=quantity;
    }
}
```

--

```
public class Hardware {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Items> allItems =new ArrayList<Items>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;
        while(true){

            System.out.println("Inventory\n");

            System.out.print("1.) Add new items to your inventory. \n");
            System.out.print("2.) Delete items from your inventory.\n");
            System.out.print("3.) Change quantity of an item.\n");

            System.out.print("6.) Exit\n");
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your Menu Choice: ");

            choice = input.nextInt();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            switch(choice){

                case 1:
                    Items myItems = new Items();
                    System.out.println("Item:");
                    myItems.setItem(in.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("Quantity?");
                    myItems.setQuantity(in.nextLine());

                    allItems.add(myItems);
                    System.out.println(allItems);

                    System.out.println("The inventory contains the following items:");
                    for(int i = 0; i < allItems.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(allItems.get(i).getName());

                    }

                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default :
                    System.out.println("This is not a valid Menu Option! Please Select Another");
                    break;

             }

        }


     }
```

}

Comment: You don't even need equals, but it could make your code easier. Just loop through your items and try to find the item that has the name entered by the user.

Comment: You have to transmit allItems to some method which would delete desirable items from it. Say, you have to declare some method `deleteSpecificItem(List<Items> allItems, string itemName)` Then declare new method `replaceSpecificItemInList(List<Items> allItems, string itemName, Items newItem)`

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `equals` method in the Items class like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object object){
   if(this == object){
      return true;
   }
   if(object instanceof Items){
      Items newItem = (Item) object;
      return item.equals(newItem.item) && quantity.equals(newItem.quantity);
   }
   return false;
}
```

Then for the removing and changing options, create an `Item` object with the user inputs, and loop over through the `List`, compare each `Item` object with the one created with the user inputs, until you find the desired object, and then perform the necessary action.

Comment: thank you for your reply. 

But if a create a new object - then I must also fill in the quantity of the object that I want to delete?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < allItems.size(); i++)
 if (allItems.get(i).getName().equals(myObj))
System.out.println(allItems.get(i).getName()); 

??

Comment: @HelmiGranfelt Are you at the very beginning of learning Java? This is deletion code: `static void deleteSpecificItem(List<Items> allItems, String itemName) {
     Iterator<Items> iter = allItems.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Items value = (Items)iter.next();
            if(Objects.equals(value.getName(), new String(itemName)))
            {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
 }` Please let me know whether you're beginner. I'll teach you the rest.